# Find out where a style comes from

Tags: wpf

I've got a control with buttons. When I  use the control in two different applications is shows up differently. Buttons in one application are flat and in the other not. I need to find out why they become flat in the one application.

I've read in similar threads to use Snoop. Snoop indeed shows that the flat buttons have a transparent background (which makes it appear flat) and that this value comes from a style. But it it does not tell where the style originates from.

**My question is**: How can I find out where a style is set onto a control Looking into the code does not reveal anything to me.

Comment: Search for `{x:Type Button}`. The global style should look this

Comment: please, show xaml  code of your button.

Comment: Just totally plain: `<Button>Hello</Button>`

Comment: ´{x:Type Button}´ is used often to create a specific button style which is applied to most of the buttons. But in this case it is about a plain button.

Comment: In case you're using Visual Studio, try WPF Tree Visualizer.

Comment: Does the tree view visualizer tell where a property is being set?